# Will Firefox OS support C libs?

Tags: firefox-os

I'm developing a cross-mobile platform framework using C as base. Then i will make some wrappers for each specific platform (like ios, android, bb). One of my targets platform is firefox-os. I de like to know if will be possible to use c libs in firefox-os, but i couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: it's built on the Linux kernel so it will probably need c libraries to run period.

Comment: Well, but this not guarantees that i will be able to use it in my apps =/

Comment: Yes maybe not. Especially since all Firefox OS Apps are suppose to be written in HTML5. Then again if your app is written in HTML5, it would be cross platform already.

Comment: With that said, you are not really suppose to write apps for android in C either but I'm sure you can because like FireFox OS, the actual OS is written in C.

Comment: C is the minimum common denominator, for all those platforms,  so i only need to write code once. That was my ideia

Comment: Well it won't work like that iOS uses Objective-C for it's gui. Android uses Java, BB uses Java and I understand Firefox OS will use HTML5. Anyone who's Anyone is using HTML5 for cross-platform apps.

Comment: The framework does not aim gui. Java has JNA and objetive c support native c code. So that's ok. My problem is firefox os.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the following Firefox OS architecture document it should answer your questions:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Architecture

For example, under Gaia it says, "Its only interface to the underlying operating system is through Open Web APIs, which are implemented by Gecko." That means that Javascript is the only interface you have to lower-level calls provided they are available via the Open Web APIs.

Comment: I read that too, but i was thinking they maybe release something like android NDK. But after 2 days of research and couldn't find anythig i guess there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be compiling your C code to JavaScript with [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten). Firefox will implement [asmjs](http://asmjs.org/) in the near future, so the compiled code will probably be very performant (since emscripten will target asmjs as output).

Comment: Right, let's say I want to use ffmpeg for a video player with support for various formats. Even on my dev machine compilation of ffmpeg takes a couple of minutes. Now imagine doing that on a battery powered arm device. Brilliant!

Comment: Who was talking about compiling anything on a mobile device? You compile anywhere you want, the output is JavaScript code, and then you run the JavaScript code in the browser.

Comment: asmjs is a "ahead of time" compiler

Comment: *1. step*: you compile your C/C++ code anywhere you want with emscripten and you get JavaScript as output that conforms to the asm.js spec. This step takes several minutes as you write. *2. step*: the client browser downloads your compiled asm.js conformant JavaScript code, parses it and generates assembly code from it. It is very fast since there's almost 1:1 correspondence between asm.js code and assembly (hence the name). *3. step*: it runs the code. It is very fast again, since it's in assembly now.

Comment: It still needs to perform many steps of a classical compiler: run lexer, build AST, emit bytecode and whatnot. Emscripten also cannot handle assembly sources which makes it useless for projects such as ffmpeg. But here is a crazy thought: Mozilla could allow distribution of **gasp** precompiled bytecode and I could take full advantage of the hardware. The missing C API makes FirefoxOS completely uninteresting for me, which is a pity.

Comment: Yeah the inline assembly of ffmpeg might be a problem here. I wonder if there's a way to turn such optimizations off and compile that with emscripten. Precompiled bytecode would be nice but that comes with its own problems I think. Maybe if Firefox would adopt Chrome's Native Client, but it seems very unlikely.